# How to search which storyboard is used from name of view controller class

Tags: xcode, storyboard

As stated in title, how can I know from view controller class name which storyboard is used for the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit late but I' answering to my own question. It's super EASY.

#### 1. Open "Find in Project..." on Xcode

I always use short cut key to open it.

Just use "Shift + Command + F"

[image: Open "Find in Project..." paned on Xcode]

#### 2. Search with your view controller class name

It just finds a storyboard with the view controller name attached.

You might want to change "Ignoring Case" search option to "Matching Case" that you get less noise.

[image: Search with a ViewController class name]

Comment: Interesting, this isn't working for me for some reason. I'm running XCode 11.3.

Comment: @Jonathan You probably have set Matching Case setting instead of Ignoring Case.